# JSON jQuery if statement

Tags: jquery, json, if-statement

I want to be able to append the `title_coupon` value from the `deal.options` object but only if it exists. If `options` doesn't exist I want to get the `title.coupon` from `data.deal`. The below code works but it's obviously returning `title.coupon` from both `deal.options` and `data.deal`. Can someone help me construct the if statement?

This is my current code:

```
$.each(data.deal, function (x, deal) {
    $('#container').after('<tr><td>' + this.title_coupon + '</td><td>' + this.id + '</td></tr>');
    $.each(deal.options, function (x, options) {
        $.each(options, function (x, deal) {
            $('#container').append('<tr><td>' + this.title_coupon + '</td><td>' + this.id + '</td></tr>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is `if statement`?

Comment: it's not there, that's what i'm looking for :)

Comment: can you provide the JSON and the expected HTML?

Comment: `jquery` is just a library of `javascript`, use simple `if()` statement and fetch conditional data

Comment: A few things. This is very hard to read. You declare `x` multiple times, each time hiding the outer instance. The same with `deal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$.each(data.deal, function (x, deal) {
    var found = false;
    $.each(deal.options, function (x, options) {
        $.each(options, function (x, deal) {
            $('#container').append('<tr><td>' + this.title_coupon + '</td><td>' + this.id + '</td></tr>');
            found = true;
        });
    });
    if (!found) {
        $('#container').after('<tr><td>' + this.title_coupon + '</td><td>' + this.id + '</td></tr>');
    }
});
```